# Page Object Model in playwright typscript gets Linting Error of Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, playwright

I'm new to playwright and I was doing page object model using typescript. The script is working fine unless when running check for linting. In github, linting is part of Pull Request Check so it is failing there.

This is my login page where it fails on linting check

```
import { Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class LoginPage {
    readonly page: Page;
    readonly userName: any;
    readonly password: any;
    readonly loginButton: any;

    constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.userName = this.page.locator('[data-qa="login-input-email"]');
        this.password = this.page.locator('[data-qa="login-input-password"]');
        this.loginButton = this.page.locator('[data-qa="login-button"]');
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} text
     */
    async enterUsername(text) {
        await this.userName.fill(text);
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} text
     */
    async enterPassword(text) {
        await this.password.fill(text);
    }

    async clickLoginBtn() {
        await this.loginButton.click();
    }
}
```

And when running the lint command below in the terminal

> npx eslint "./src/**" --cache

This is the error it is getting.

> C:\Users\path\Desktop\path\Workspace\path\path\src\portal\locators\common\CommonPage.ts
> 5:13  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (5:13)

The error pertains to these declarations

```
readonly page: Page;
readonly userName: any;
readonly password: any;
readonly loginButton: any;
```

This is the content of .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },

    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "overrides": [
        {
            "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "files": [
            ".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "sourceType": "script",
            }
        }
    ],
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "babelOptions": {
          "babelrc": false,
          "configFile": false
        },
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea on this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using `@babel/eslint-parser` as your parser, which is designed to parse JavaScript code, not Typescript.  To parse Typescript code, you should use `@typescript-eslint/parser` instead.

You need to install

```
npm install -D eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

Then update your `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "overrides": [
        {
            "env": {
                "node": true
            },
            "files": [
                ".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"
            ],
            "parserOptions": {
                "sourceType": "script",
            }
        }
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "requireConfigFile": false,
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module",
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint" 
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error for that:

======> "WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=4.7.4 <5.4.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 5.4.2"

Comment: you can install correct version of typescript - uninstall old one line `npm uninstall typescript` and then install `npm i typescript@4.7.4`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Ｒの卄ＩＴ. Although linting is still working. Our team is encouraged to use updated packages. I think I am all good since that is just a warning. Thanks a lot ggorlen